# How do I create an instance of a nested class from within that class in Python?

Tags: python, oop, inner-classes

```
class ExampleClass():
    def Example(self):
        self.nestedinstance = self.NestedClass()
        self.nestedinstance.makenew()


    class NestedClass():
        def makenew(self):
            newclass = NestedClass()

ExampleClass().Example()
```

When I run the above code I get the exception: `name 'NestedClass' is not defined`

Is there a different way to do this with a nested class or have I done something wrong?

Comment: `NestedClass` is **only** accessible via the class, even in `makenew` you'd have to use `ExampleClass.NestedClass()`. You likely don't really need to nest classes.

Comment: Please post a stacktrace, because in this case it would have made it very clear where the error is coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error comes from how python handles classes.

When it encounters a `class` statement, the body of the class is run, and the names it defines are placed in a separate namespace, which will eventually become the class `__dict__`. The class object is not created and bound to its name until (well) after the body has run. That means that when you put `class NestedClass:` inside the body of `class ExampleClass:`, `ExampleClass` does not exist yet, and neither does `NestedClass`. Indirectly because of this, all the new class namespaces live in the top level available namespace (e.g. global or function), and are not actually nested within one another.

As a consequence of this order of operations, class bodies are not aware of the namespaces of surrounding classes at all. So the namespace of `NestedClass` looks out to the global namespace, not to the `__dict__` of `ExampleClass`, as you might expect coming from say Java. A class defined in a function would be able to see the functions local namespace before globals, but still not that of an enclosing class.

And so, the line `newclass = NestedClass()` raises an error. The name `NestedClass` does not exist in the function's namespace, or in the global namespace. There are three simple workarounds available:

1. Use the staticly scoped `__class__`:

   ```
   newclass = __class__()
   ```
2. Refer to the class by its global name:

   ```
   newclass = ExampleClass.NestedClass()
   ```
3. Don't use nested classes in Python. This is generally the preferred approach. Just move `NestedClass` to the top level. Then your `makenew` method will work without modification, and `ExampleClass.Example` can refer to `NestedClass` directly instead of as `self.NestedClass`.

Answer (score 2):

You ideally want to be using classmethods if creating a new instance, this is an example of how you'd do it:

```
class NestedClass():
    @classmethod
    def makenew(cls):
        newclass = cls()
```

Alternatively if you wanted to create an instance using the current instance (for example if you needed to pass in some arguments), then you can get the class by using `type(self)` or `self.__class__`.

```
class NestedClass():
    def makenew(self):
        newclass = type(self)()
```

Without knowing your use case though, this may not be what you're after.